# Can I use TLSv1.0 for one client IP, TLS v1.2 for everyone else

Tags: ssl, virtualhost, apache-2.4

Something like this?

```
# TLS v1.0+ for one IP

<VirtualHost _default_:443>

    Order deny,allow // <------------- HERE
    Deny from all // <------------- HERE
    Allow from 10.20.30.40 // <------------- HERE

    SSLProtocol all -SSLv2 -SSLv3 
    SSLCipherSuite          ECDHE-RSA-AES128-GCM-SHA256:ECDHE-ECDSA-AES128-GCM-SHA256:ECDHE-RSA-AES256-GCM-SHA384:ECDHE-ECDSA-AES256-GCM-SHA384:DHE-RSA-AES128-GCM-SHA256:DHE-DSS-AES128-GCM-SHA256:kEDH+AESGCM:ECDHE-RSA-AES128-SHA256:ECDHE-ECDSA-AES128-SHA256:ECDHE-RSA-AES128-SHA:ECDHE-ECDSA-AES128-SHA:ECDHE-RSA-AES256-SHA384:ECDHE-ECDSA-AES256-SHA384:ECDHE-RSA-AES256-SHA:ECDHE-ECDSA-AES256-SHA:DHE-RSA-AES128-SHA256:DHE-RSA-AES128-SHA:DHE-DSS-AES128-SHA256:DHE-RSA-AES256-SHA256:DHE-DSS-AES256-SHA:DHE-RSA-AES256-SHA:!aNULL:!eNULL:!EXPORT:!DES:!RC4:!3DES:!MD5:!PSK
    SSLHonorCipherOrder     on
    SSLCompression          off

    ...

</VirtualHost>

# TLS v1.2 for everyone else

<VirtualHost _default_:443>

    Order allow,deny // <------------- HERE
    Deny from 10.20.30.40 // <------------- HERE
    Allow from * // <------------- HERE

    SSLProtocol -all +TLSv1.2
    SSLCipherSuite ECDHE-RSA-AES256-GCM-SHA384:ECDHE-ECDSA-AES256-GCM-SHA384:ECDHE-RSA-AES256-SHA384:ECDHE-ECDSA-AES256-SHA384:ECDHE-RSA-AES256-SHA:ECDHE-ECDSA-AES256-SHA:DHE-DSS-AES256-GCM-SHA384:DHE-RSA-AES256-GCM-SHA384:DHE-RSA-AES256-SHA256:DHE-DSS-AES256-SHA256:DHE-RSA-AES256-SHA:DHE-DSS-AES256-SHA:AECDH-AES256-SHA:ADH-AES256-GCM-SHA384:ADH-AES256-SHA256:ADH-AES256-SHA:ECDH-RSA-AES256-GCM-SHA384:ECDH-ECDSA-AES256-GCM-SHA384:ECDH-RSA-AES256-SHA384:ECDH-ECDSA-AES256-SHA384:ECDH-RSA-AES256-SHA:ECDH-ECDSA-AES256-SHA:AES256-GCM-SHA384:AES256-SHA256:AES256-SHA:ECDHE-RSA-DES-CBC3-SHA:ECDHE-ECDSA-DES-CBC3-SHA:EDH-RSA-DES-CBC3-SHA:EDH-DSS-DES-CBC3-SHA:AECDH-DES-CBC3-SHA:ADH-DES-CBC3-SHA:ECDH-RSA-DES-CBC3-SHA:ECDH-ECDSA-DES-CBC3-SHA:DES-CBC3-SHA
    SSLHonorCipherOrder on
    SSLCompression off

    ...

</VirtualHost>
```

Edit:

I have also an idea to create 2nd VirtualHost for different port lets says 344 and forward/route port 443 to 344 for that specific IP. Is it possible?

Comment: _In theory_ it is possible but I don't think OpenSSL (or maybe mod_ssl) actually does it.

Comment: @MichaelHampton maybe its doable with little help of iptables (or my mikrotik router)? for example I could run another VirtualHost on different port and filter+redirect request for that IP from port 443 to another?

Comment: you might be able to do a redirect before, think of something like rewriteurl.
you use www.example.com (do the rewrite to tls10.example.com based on ip ,otherwise tls1.2.example.com) 
then have your "normal" apache virtual hosts respond to those subdomains differently as you want.
Sadly i lack enough info to check if rewriteurl is capable of that.

Comment: @Dennis i would need two certs or wildcart cert

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Create two virtualhosts, differing only in the port that is used.

Use iptables to conditionally redirect the selected IP to the TLS 1.0 instance.

```
iptables -t nat -A PREROUTING -s CLIENT_OF_INTEREST -p tcp --dport 443 -j REDIRECT --to-port 344
```

Although, I must add that doing so would leave me feeling a bit yuck. It would be better, if at all possible, to make the client able to do TLS 1.2.

eg. if its Java, make sure you have the 'unlimited' crypto bits added on.

But I quite understand that this is not always possible.

Comment: thanks, it looks nice i'll test it. it is yuck but i need to make workaround for old software

Comment: i am geting `ip_tables: REDIRECT target: only valid in nat table, not filter` i guess I would have to set it up on my mikrotik

Comment: Why not have the "stupid" client use a different port?

Comment: @peter you need to add `-t nat`

Comment: And `-A PREROUTING`, sorry.

Answer (score 2):

Yes, it's possible, you can set SSLProtocol directive for each virtualhost.

Sample config you posted seems to be OK but you are using *default* virtualhosts. You must better use IP:Port.

http://httpd.apache.org/docs/2.4/mod/mod_ssl.html#sslprotocol

https://httpd.apache.org/docs/2.4/mod/core.html#virtualhost

Comment: I have only one virtualhost... I want to set SSLProtocol for client IP